# right side panel on hover is flickering

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi guys i have tried what you had given to me.. but what wrong am i doing
see my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/Ej5k8/

```
 body {

position: relative;
min-height: 3000px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
top: 0;
font-family:'proximanova-regular', sans-serif;
 }
```

when you hover over the right top button the silde keep flickering and not like the example i want on  http://yahoo.tumblr.com/

Comment: check the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ej5k8/3/)

Comment: This is why: The trigger element become "hidden" when you animate your sidemenu. Which means the mouse actually leave the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your **mouseleave** handler to not use `#follow` but the content panel itself.

Plus do a `:animated` check to ensure you don't activate mouseleave when the content panel is on its way to being fully displayed.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ej5k8/2/

**Code:**

```
$("#panel-content").mouseleave(function () {
    if(!$("#panel-content").is(':animated')) {
        $("#panel-content").show();
        $("#panel-content").animate({
            width: '0px'
        }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: instead of using fast or slow can i use a value? and instead of overlay how do i use the move left. I meant the whole content needs to move on the left and the black not overlay. In simple words i wnt the black panel to push the content to left

Comment: Yes, instead of 'fast' or 'slow', you can use a number to specify the duration in milliseconds.

Comment: And you can make to push the content to the left, by a) not making its parent absolute but floating and b) removing float: right from panel-content

Comment: i tried here http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/Ej5k8/8/  what am i doing wrong i did as per your advice

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `mouseleave` on `#panel-content` instead of `#follow` button to avoid the flicker.

[Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/Ej5k8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#panel-content").hide();
$("#follow").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#panel-content").show();
    $("#panel-content").animate({
        width: '300px'
    }, 'slow');
});
$("#panel-content").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#panel-content").show();
    $("#panel-content").animate({
        width: '0px'
    }, 'slow');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ej5k8/7/)